# Atom - What is "Project Home" under settings?

Tags: github, project, atom-editor

I am extremely new to this stuff and I am wondering ...

- On the text editor - Atom
- Under settings it says "`Project Home`" ...
- and then a file w/:

  ```
  Default: Users/myname/github
  ```

What is that?

Does that mean when I save stuff in Atom that is where it goes?

Is it on my computer or on the Github site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [issue 2031](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2031) also convey the same question:

> > There has been some confusion about what `Project Home` is supposed to represent, myself included.

The answer was:

> Just as an addendum, I've got a PR open at [atom/package-generator#16](https://github.com/atom/package-generator/pull/16) to use "`project home`" as the place to create new Atom packages.

(that is where the [`/github` part comes from](https://github.com/atom/package-generator/pull/16/files), and it is on your computer)

> I'd also second @kelunik's assumption about it being used as the default directory, to be used when launched from the local dock or start menu analog, perhaps.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer... and please bare with me on the novice questions. ha ha.

Comment: @Lucas No problem: on this site, we are *all* novice, on one topic or the other.